# Not able to retrieve project users and companies from BIM360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge

After obtaining a 3-legged token I can retrieve hubs, projects, checklists, issues, and other related project data, but when I query the endpoints listed below using the same token I get back a **403 status** accompanied with the following error:

```
*"developerMessage": "Token does not have the privilege for this request.",
"moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
"errorCode": "AUTH-010"*
```

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/

Could you please give me some insights here?

Thanks,

Henrique Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a 2-legged token for the [Get companies](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/) endpoint.

About [Get Project users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/), please check the scopes of your token.

The successful endpoints (retrieve [hubs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/), [projects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/), [checklists](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-GET/), and [issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/)) require `data:read` scope, while [Get Project users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/) require `account:read` scope.